# Connecting to LAN with specific IP

Tags: lan

I am totally a newbie to Ubuntu. I am trying to connect to LAN. Here is the screenshot of what I do in windows to connect to that network:

[image]

But in Ubuntu while editing connection with specific IP address I can't save it and continue. Need some help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you clicked on DNS server field? After clicking that field Save option become active. If that didn't help put a DNS server value something like 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this method :

open terminal :

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

you can add the following

```
iface eth0 inet static (eth0 is the name of my interface )
address (your Ip)
netmask (your netmask)
gateway (gateway)
dns-nameservers (your dns )
```

save and quit

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to make an Ad Hoc connection to another computer, not the router. If that is correct, please be certain that you have selected Mode: Ad Hoc. If this is not the case, please edit your question to clarify your intent.